# ## in front of Coldfusion variable

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

```
<CFQUERY Name="LoadCompletions"  datasource="#request.datasource#"> 
SELECT n.*, u.UserID into ##Completions
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=#Destination_File#',
        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') n
    inner join LE_User u on 's'+n.id = u.login_name
</cfquery>
```

I checked all over google to see what ##Completions means. Could someone help me out please? When I try to dump it, its giving the same thing ##Completions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `##` is to escape a literal `#` so it is part of the SQL passed to the database. (As opposed to marking a CFML hash expression.)

`#tablename` is Microsoft SQL Server syntax for a [local temporary table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx).

The `Completions` bit is just an arbitrary table name (hence why searching for it wouldn't bring up anything relevant).

Note that there are also global temporary tables, written as `##tablename`, which would need to be escaped to `####tablename` in cfquery.

Comment: Just one question though. You said this is a local temporary table with one # acting as an escape literal but in the link that you gave, it says ##tablename is a global temporary table. So to create a global temp table, it should be ###tablename when using Coldfusion?

Comment: No, because escaping requires pairs, so `###tablename` would be an escaped hash followed by an unclosed hash expression (so a syntax error). You must have an even number of hashes. (This isn't any different to how escaping works in other languages - e.g. in JS, you can't write `\'''` - you must do `\'\'\'` - it's basically the same thing.)

Comment: oh..escaping the escape character, but looks like no escape for me from coldfusion LOL.